# Ability to shift attention quickly and continue conversations from years ago seamlessly

Tags: memory, attention

Noam Chomsky asserted that he has "sort of buffers in the brain that allow [him] to shift back and forth from one project to the other and store one" and that he "can pick up after a long stretch and be more or less where [he] left off". He also mentioned having friends with this ability, "in particular, one friend who [he] would meet every five or six years and usually pick up the conversation [they] had been having as if [they] had just had it five minutes ago and go on from there" [1].

This ability was corroborated by individuals close to him, including Bev Stohl [2].

Is there a psychological or neuroscientific definition of this ability, and if so, does this ability exist on a spectrum?

[1] https://chomsky.info/1991____/

[2] https://www.reddit.com/r/chomsky/comments/zf2elw/comment/iz9tzw9/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3